# Formtastic / rails forms not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, formtastic

I am trying to use formtastic to make a form where I can enter an :opposition choose a :venue and a :team and then be presented with a list of players that I am able to check off to select them for the

I have got the form set up so it renders correctly however when submitted it does not save any information and just reloads the page.

My code is at my github here: https://github.com/jpknegtel/st_francis

## models

This concerns the following models:

**player**

```
 has_many :player_fixtures
 has_many :fixtures, :through => :player_fixtures
```

**fixtures**

```
 has_many :player_fixtures
 has_many :players, :through => :player_fixtures
```

**PlayerFixture**

```
belongs_to :player
belongs_to :fixture
```

## controller

```
def create
@fixture = Fixture.new(params[:fixture])
if @fixture.save
  flash[:notice] = "Fixture Created"
  redirect_to(:action =>'list')
else
  flash.now[:error] = "Could not save fixture. Please re-enter information"
  render('new')
end
end

def new
 @fixture = Fixture.new
end
```

## form

```
<%= semantic_form_for :fixture do |f| %>
 <%= f.inputs do %>
  <%= f.input :opposition  %>
  <%= f.input :team, :as => :select, :collection => Team.all %>
  <%= f.input :venue, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Hash[Venue.all.map{|b| [b.name, b.id]}]%>
  <%= f.input :players, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Hash[Player.all.map{|b| [b.full_name, b.id]}], :required => true  %>
<% end %>
<%= f.actions do %>
 <%=  f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
 <%=  f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

So when the form is submitted now nothing is passed. When looking at the web brick server nothing gets submitted but the page just gets reloaded.

It is possible to insert the records using rails console.

EDIT: I can now see this when submitted.

```
Started POST "/fixtures/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-23 15:00:21 +0100
Processing by FixturesController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"Hx4TChWiUdhpZbAfgWUYMWBKao86pZh0tGzwVKy+P80=", "fixture"=> {"opposition"=>"Mid sussex", "team"=>"1", "venue"=>["", "1"], "players"=>["", "1", "3"]}, "button"=>""}
Team Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` 
Venue Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `venues`.* FROM `venues` 
Player Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` 
Rendered fixtures/new.html.erb within layouts/application (173.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 163.0ms | ActiveRecord: 36.0ms)
[2012-04-23 15:00:21] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set     content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: There's no 'semantic_form_for' in that repo. Did you commit all your latest stuff?

Comment: I have just pushed the commit. It should be there now, sorry about that.

Comment: Can you post the code for your controller's `new` action? Are you assigning `@fixture` there?

Comment: Try using `semantic_form_for @fixture`...

Comment: Have put the new controller in, getting the following error `undefined method `fixtures_path' for #<#<Class:0x4829838>:0x482be00>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is massassignment. You need to allow rails to update some attributes via massassignment.

Add this line to your fixtures model:

```
attr_accessible :players_attributes, :opposition, :team_id, :venue_id, :date
```

This allows rails to set these attributes via `new` and `update_attributes` methods.

See the [rails guide on security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) for more information.

Comment: I have added the following however I can not seem to do anything differnt. Still reloads instantly. But have seen this now: See edit above

Comment: Could you post some more log? I would like to have a look at the log output for the request of the form and then the output when you submit the form.

Comment: have added some more. I can not see much else of use to be honest?

Comment: But this is not when you submit. This is only for the request of the form. Can you please add the log output when you click the button? (for `/fixtures/create`).

Comment: Okay the /create now works. Thank you. (I understand it should be /new however this will do for now)

Comment: However I still need players to be inserted into the join table. This is not happening at the moment. Even though it is passed in the params.

Comment: What do you mean with /create works? What are you doing exactly? And what is happening?

Comment: If I go to fixtures/create and insert data into the form it submits fine, however if I go to fixtures/new and insert the excat same data nothing is passed to the database and the form is just reloaded.

Comment: Mhh the rails way would be that you go to /fixtures/new and only there you see the form, you enter your data and the form sends your data to /fixtures/create when you work with the data (validate, etc) and save it. It seems strange to me that you have 2 websites for the form...
Maybe your record does not get saved because the validations fail. Just for testing comment out the validation line in the fixture model and try again.