# Routing error rails "Couldn't find Fixture with id=list" when url = /fixtures/list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a fixture controller that was working fine,

However now it doesnt seem to work any more.
I have the following in the fixtures_controller

```
def list
  @fixture = Fixture.all
```

Please see my github for the files https://github.com/jpknegtel/st_francis

If anyone could shed some light onto this it would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Looking at your code, you do not at all have routes. You need routes for telling rails how to map the url from the request to the controllers and the actions within. Routes go in the `config/routes.rb` file.

Your problem is that you do not have a route for `/fixtures/list`. Rails thinks you want to show the fixture with the ID list. And does not find any record and throws an error.

You need to add some routes. I highly recommend to read the [rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). And I also recommend the use of ressourceful routing.

If you adopt the method names in your controllers this is really easy, otherwise you have to do a lot of work on your own. Read exspecially section 2. It took quite a while for me to understand RESTful routes, so do not give up - you will love them one day. If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hello, after seeing this and quickly looking at the guide you suggested; I looked at the routes file and the following was in there. resources :fixtures so I took it out and everything seems to work fine. Would you suggest leaving it like this?

Comment: With removing the `resources :fixtures` line, you get the old unrestful routing. This works, but it is not as "beautiful" as the RESTful one. It is up to you to decide which way you want to go. I would go the RESTful way. I could try helping you to implement the RESTful way, if you want so.

Comment: This is not my biggest worry for my project at the moment. Would you be able to have a look at my other question located here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261401/formtastic-rails-forms-not-submitting#comment13194605_10261401